# on hover background should appear like spearhead shape(WITHOUT SPECIFYING WIDTH)

Tags: css

[image]

On hover i want to fill baackground color which takes a shape of spearhead "WITHOUT SPECIFYING WIDTH".
I have the folliowing code:,

html:

```
 <div class="menu">
<ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Business Verticals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Solution Partners</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>


      </div>
```

css:

```
.menu ul li{list-style:none;float:left;padding: 15px 66px;border-right:1px     solid #032f3e;}
 .menu ul li:last-child{margin-right:0;border-right:none;}
 .menu ul li a{text-decoration:none;color:#fff; font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';font-size:15px;}
 .menu ul li a:hover{color:#ab987a;}
```

Comment: But that they have specified width,but the content inside it may vary,how to do it without using width?

Comment: the second link does not specify a width. If it does, then it is only an optional property

Comment: Yes, both the answers in the second link can be adapted to work without specifying width.